# Inquisitive Badge - Downvote and then Updownvote

Tags: support, badges

I wonder how the Inquisitive badge process works in case of a downvote which eventually has been "updownvoted". Did the positive question record break when the downvote occurred?

Comment: Why would you ask?   :)

Comment: Because I received a downvote on a question, and then that downvote has been updownvoted (several days later). So I wondered if my "positive question-record" was broken at the point of the downvote or if the latter had saved it some days later. Just for curiosity ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only tag-badges are ever revoked (barring gross fraud and manual SE intervention).

And a badge is awarded if you fulfill the requirements *when it is checked*.
"Maintain a positive question-record" doesn't actually look at history, but at how things look now, taking into account all your questions, deleted or not.

Because checking eligibility is quite expensive for most badges, and eligibility seldom changes, those checks are batched and scheduled at regular intervals, for example daily for tag-badges.